# SQL Select from into (How to keep the default values in new table)

Tags: mysql, sql

here is my code,

```
SELECT *
INTO new_table
FROM old_table
```

is there a way to keep the default values when creating a new table where the SQL statement must be (SELECT *) and not select certain fields.

Maybe something like this??

```
SELECT *
INTO new_table
FROM old_table
VALUES (DEFAULT)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*default values*"?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data to to illustrate your example? Default values are just the values the db engine uses when one is not specified during an insert. Since you're using `SELECT *`, you're technically providing values for each column.

Comment: if the columns are not part of the insert and there is a default value then the default value will be added to the column

Comment: Why must the statement be `SELECT *`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, some examples would be good. If you want to copy just the structure of the table (no rows) you can use the below:

```
SELECT * INTO newtable
FROM oldtable
WHERE 1 = 0;
```

Comment: Copying the structure is better done with `CREATE TABLE newtable LIKE oldtable;`

Comment: But I don't think that's what he's asking about.

Comment: only the columns and identity but not indexes, contrainsts and others

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet will be to use `ALTER TABLE` after your `SELECT ... INTO`.

Something like this:

```
SELECT *
INTO new_table
FROM old_table

ALTER TABLE new_table ALTER SomeColumnName SET DEFAULT 1000;
```

Comment: Oh, you want to preserve the defaults in the old table for the new table?  Use CREATE TABLE ... LIKE for that.

Comment: OP wants to use `SELECT * INTO`, though.